# How to change data type of stl containers in API without breaking existing application?

Tags: c++, stl

I've a library based c++ where many API has stl container as parameter. And stl container's are int type. Like

```
f1(std::vector<int> items)
f2(std::map<int, int> mp)
```

Now int type needed to be changed into long long int (64 bit integer). Like

```
f1(std::vector<long long int> items)
f2(std::map<long long int, int> mp)
```

Lots of application has already been developed based on that library. If I changed API signature from int to long long int that will break those applications. And as there are many API I don't want to overload every API.

Is there a way to support long long int in those API without breaking existing applications and without using function overloading?

Is it possible to create a wrapper class which will implicitly convert itself to std::vector or std::vector based on function calling?

Comment: I think overloading each function would be less work than creating a wrapper class. You could also template each function. Existing calls will call `f1<vector<int>>` and new calls will call `f1<vector<long long>>`.

Comment: How are callers (or the new wrapper class) supposed to know to which one to convert? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Anyway, the cleanest way of proceeding is not overloading either. Simply provide a completely new API (possibly under a parallel namespace), and keep support for the old one (the old one may be simply forwarding calls to the new, more general one).

Comment: Use function templates that are not ambiguous with your existing functions. That way existing functionalities are not effected and more data types would be supported.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, that if you don't want existing applications to break, you cannot require them to change their code. If you need the 64-bit integers in your API internally, you can just cast the elements (or copy the input vectors), but since the passed parameters are most likely 32-bit integer, the additional information that a `long long` can store aren't there anyway. If you want to pass effectively 64-bit of data, the client code has to change.

**EDIT:** If newer implementations should be able to use `long long`, then I suggest overloading to be your best option. Casting to `vector<int>` will lose information  and changing the signature of the only method will break current clients. When someone calls the old variant you can cast the single elements to `long long`. If you want to store the whole vector, just copy it.

I also suggest to pass the vector by (const) reference, you can avoid an unnessecary copy of possible large data and it will not break clients, since the calling syntax stays the same.

Comment: I want existing application able to use container like std::vector<int> but newer applications to use container like std::vector<long long int>

Comment: Updated my answer